# Fuel\Core\FuelException [ Error ]:!! セッションデータファイルを保存するパスへの書き込みアクセス権を持たしたい

Tags: apache, fuelphp

https.confやhttpd-vhosts.confを設定し、
URLを打ち込むと、下記のようなエラーが出ます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
Fuel\Core\FuelException [ Error ]:
The webserver doesn't have write access to the path to store the session data files.

COREPATH/classes/session/file.php @ line 341
```

Webサーバーは、セッションデータファイルを保存するパスへの書き込みアクセス権を持っていません！との事ですが、どのようにしたら「セッションデータファイルを保存するパスへの書き込みアクセス権を持たす」事が出来るのでしょうか？

ネットで調べたりしましたが、なかなか解決につながるような情報にアクセスできません。

どなたかお手数おかけしますが、ご回答頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: http://fuelphp.jp/docs/1.8/classes/session/config.html こちらを確認するとデフォルト`/tmp`になっていますが、/tmpフォルダはありますか？また自前でSessionのパスの設定を変えたりしていれば追記お願いします

Comment: あとタイトルは具体的な問題をまとめたタイトルを書くようにしましょう。このタイトルだと何が問題なのかわかりません。

Comment: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/■■■■/fuel/manage/tmp ありました。この/tmpに書き込みアクセス権を付与してあげるイメージでしょうか？

Comment: アクセスに成功しました！ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/■■■■/fuel/manage/tmpの、この/tmpに書き込みアクセス権を読み/書きにしてあげると解決できました。